# Is the number of vertices of a graph equal to or greater than half of the graph's average degree?

Tags: graph

Is the number of vertices of a graph equal to or greater than half of the graph's average degree?
Can anybody give me a proof?

Comment: Sometimes. Not always. You can construct a graph with 10 vertices and average degree 9, and you can construct a graph with 10 vertices and average degree 0.

Comment: The maximum average degree is obtained when the graph is complete. In that case, the average degree is the number of vertices minus 1. So the number of vertices of a graph is always greater than the average degree, hence greater than half of it. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of Vertices in graph is always greater than graph's degree, because, the maximum graph's degree is when the graph is complete with degree of `Vertices - 1`.

I think you meant [Handshacking Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) that is "In any graph, the sum of all the vertex-degree is equal to twice the number of edges."

Comment: Thanks for your reply